# How to get the downloaded file name?

Tags: android, download

I have downloaded a file using `DownloadManager`, now i need to unzip that file automatically after it is downloaded, is there a way to get the name of that file?

More about my question:
The downloadmanager is downloading multiple tasks, and once one task is finished, it broadcasts this completion to a receiver, now my problem is how to pass the name of that file to the receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You supplied the path for the download to `DownloadManager`. Hence, you already know "the name of the file". You simply need to hold onto that information for use once the download is complete.

Comment: but my problem is, the downloadmanager is downloading multiple tasks, and once one task is finished, it broadcasts this completion to a receiver, now my problem is how to pass the name of that file to the receiver?

Comment: @Jolin: IIRC, the download ID is supplied in an `Intent` extra on the broadcast. You get this ID from your `enqueue()` call. You will need to track the file being downloaded by its ID to associate that with the local filename.